# How to find rows containing integers given in a file?

Tags: regex, search, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have a file `dict` containing one integer on each row

```
123
456
```

I want to find lines in file `file` that contain *exactly* the integers in `dict`.

If I use

```
$ grep -w -f dict file
```

I get false matches such as

```
12345  foo
23456  bar
```

These are false because `12345 != 123` and `23456 != 456`.  The problem is that the `-w` option considers digits as word characters too.  The `-x` option will not work either as the lines in `file` can have other text. What's the best way to do this please?  It will be great if the solution can offer progress monitoring and a good performance on `dict` and `file` of large sizes.

Comment: Must you use `grep`, or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: Not really.  Any command-line tool is OK.

Comment: Your `grep` command works for me without the false positives you indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly general method using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]++; next } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in array) print $0 }' dict file
```

**Explanation:**

```
FNR==NR { }  ## FNR is number of records relative to the current input file. 
             ## NR is the total number of records.
             ## So this statement simply means `while we're reading the 1st file
             ## called dict; do ...`

array[$1]++; ## Add the first column ($1) to an array called `array`.
             ## I could use $0 (the whole line) here, but since you have said
             ## that there will only be one integer per line, I decided to use
             ## $1 (it strips leading and lagging whitespace; if any)

next         ## process the next line in `dict`

for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  ## loop through each column in `file`

if ($i in array)       ## if one of these columns can be found in the array

print $0               ## print the whole line out
```

**To process multiple files using bash loop:**

```
## This will process files; like file, file1, file2, file3 ...
## And create output files like, file.out, file1.out, file2.out, file3.out ...

for j in file*; do awk -v FILE=$j.out 'FNR==NR { array[$1]++; next } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in array) print $0 > FILE }' dict $j; done
```

**If you are interested in using `tee` on multiple files, you may like to try something like this:**

```
for j in file*; do awk -v FILE=$j.out 'FNR==NR { array[$1]++; next } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in array) { print $0 > FILE; print FILENAME, $0 } }' dict $j; done 2>&1 | tee output
```

This will show you the name of the file being process and the matching record found, and write a 'log' to file called `output`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain a little how does the program work?

Comment: Also, would the awk approach be able to monitor the progress?

Comment: @user001: If `dict` is very large, you will have no way of knowing how many numbers have been added to `array`. But when reading `file`, if a match is found, it will it will print out the matching line immediately.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it immediately prints a matching result.  That's a nice feature to have. BTW, is it possible to print the matched line and at the same time write it to a file?

Comment: Also, it's a little odd for me that `NR==FNR {}` is used to tell if the current line is in the first file.  Say, if I want to extend the program to process multiple files `file1`, `file2` with a single `dict` file, this won't work.

Comment: `next` goes to the next *line* (in the *current* file - dict - since you have `FNR == NR`).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: What was I thinking... Thanks.

Comment: @steve I only want to write the matching line not the current file into log.

Comment: @user001: Simply remove `FILENAME, `. HTH.

Comment: @steve Could you also explain a little the structure of `FNR == NR { ... } { ... }`?  What's the relation between the first and second `{ ... }`?  It's a little confusing to me. Does the second `{...}` get executed for lines in the `dict` file too?

Comment: @user001: The first set of braces is qualified by `FNR==NR`. So essentially everything inside those braces works on the first file listed. Now when awk process the second file, it will only do what's listed in the second lot of braces. When `awk` is reading this second file, `NR` continues to increment, while `FNR` stays the same. Therefore, if you wanted you _could_ actually qualify the second lot of braces with `FNR<=NR`, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Add word boundary into dict as below:

```
\<123\>
\<456\>
```

-w parameter is not required. just need:

grep -f dict file

Comment: This works.  However, when I try this with a `file` containing 20000 lines, it was very slow.  Any suggestion for improving performance? Also when it's very slow, is it possible to monitor which entry in the dictionary is being processed so I can have some idea about the progress of the program?

Comment: Please write all patterns into one line: \<123\>\|\<456\>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily using a Python script, for example:

```
import sys

numbers = set(open(sys.argv[1]).read().split("\n"))
with open(sys.argv[2]) as inf:
    for s in inf:
        if s.split()[0] in numbers:
            sys.stdout.write(s)
```

Error checking and recovery is left for the reader to implement.

Comment: Well, ideally I want to do it with GNU utilities on Bash command line.  If there are many lines of code, I can make a script.  Thanks.